# How to set dimensions of an object to default?

Tags: dimensions

I have added a cube to the center and then I changed dimensions of the cube in add cube option on left bottom.

After that I just get those dimensions as default after restart, reset settings and everything. I just can not change the dimensions to default default settings of blender(something in decimals).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply RMB click and *Reset to Default Value*

Note:
To make new cubes come in that default size, you'll need to type it in manually.
Simply resetting to default value won't work (not sure why).

[image]

Comment: Jachym Michal. Blender 2.79 and before : in the value field it was 1m (1000mm) but the field name was **Radius** and that gave a cube size of 2m. With 2.80 the field name was changed to **Size** and the default value set at 2m which also gave a 2m cube. "Hope this helps" :)

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, thanks :).